# Java Program for Palindrome number

Tags: java

I write a program in java to find if a number is palindrome or not but I got a error which says execution timed out. I think there is a problem of infinite loop but did not get it that where this infinite loop present in my code and how it can be resolve. Please resolve this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Test{
    
public static void main(String args[]){
        double d = 0;
        double b = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double N = 12321;
        double i = 0;
        double c = 0;
        double a = 0;
        while(b > 10)
        {
           
           b = N/10;
           d = d+1;
        }
        
        
            while(N >= 1)
            {
                
                c = Math.round(N%10);
                a = a + c * Math.pow(10, d-i);
                i++;
                N = Math.round(N/10);
            }
            if(a == N)
            {
                System.out.print("Number is palindrome");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Number is not palindrome");
            }
}
}
```

Comment: I think rounding here is not a good idea, 151 would be no palindrom, because `round(15/10)` is 2, which is not equal to the opposite digit

Comment: Look at the condition in your first while-loop. First, `b == 2147483647`, then in all iterations after that `b == 1232.1`. That's your infinite loop.

Comment: reversing a double number and check will not be a good idea. you can transform the input to string and check reverse string.